# Use VBA open a Excel file, and run a loop, but the loop will be always skipped

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run loop on the same workbook, but it also give me nothing. But If I run this VBA directly on the workbook (CGDSOUSD), it works well. So I am wondering how to run VBA after let VBA open a new file.

```
Dim rownumber As Integer
Dim colnumber As Integer
Dim total As Double
colnumber = 1
For colnumber = 1 To 23
  If Cells(8, colnumber) = "DELTA" Then
    total = 0
    rownumber = 9
    Do Until Cells(rownumber, colnumber) = "" And Cells(rownumber + 1, colnumber) = "" And Cells(rownumber + 5, 1) = ""
      If Cells(rownumber, 1) = "" And (Cells(rownumber, 7).Value = "DSO TROPS" Or Cells(rownumber, 8).Value = "DSO TROPS" Or Cells(rownumber, 6).Value = "DSO TROPS") Then
        total = total + (Cells(rownumber, colnumber).Value)
      Else
      End If
      rownumber = rownumber + 1
    Loop
  Else
  End If
  colnumber = colnumber + 1
Next colnumber
total = Round(total, 2)  'will be imputed into E20 in risk tools
MsgBox total
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image

Comment: You put this code on the load event...what happens if you put a breakpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work at all".  Do you mean it won't compile?  Or that it just skips over the loop?  Or it crashes on a line within the loop?  Or it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: I have added my code here, can anyone help me to figure out how to fix this bug? When I run the loop only with the file opening, the loop works well. However I will get 0 if I use VBA to open that file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Do Until` is `False`.
To iterate through cells I always determine the lastrow and use a `for` loop.
See basic example below.
ps: use `ActiveCell` and activate one.

'place a value in cell A1 to A4 for test.

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow

If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
Cells(i, 2).Value = "not empty"
End If

Next i

End Sub
```